# Rendering a beautiful square root with MathJax.

Tags: discussion, mathjax

We all know that to render a square root in $\mathit{MathJax}$ we just need to write `\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}` which will be rendered as: $$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$$ But I want to make it look prettier just like this (the left one): 
[image] 
 WikiPedia has an article about it that you can find 
[here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Roots), but the procedure they suggest doesn't work with $\mathit{MathJax}$.

So does anyone know how to make it look like shown in the left image? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The one on the left looks *worse*.

Comment: @Potato I don't think so.

Comment: On my screen (Chrome with 125% magnification), the horizontal line of the square root is detached from the left "v" part.

Comment: This two versions of root were also compared on TeX.SE: [“Closed” (square) root symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29834/closed-square-root-symbol)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Even if this can be achieved with MathJax, please leave complex TeX hacks fine-tuning typography (like ones you're linking to) for your papers — let's keep sources on Math.SE clear and simple.